# .NET MonthCalendar.ShowWeekNumbers Property - Which rule applies?

Tags: .net, week-number, monthcalendar

In .NET control `MonthCalendar` you can enable display of week number. Does anybody know which rule applies for these number?

[image]

.NET provides several rules for calculating the week number, see [Calendar.GetWeekOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - and the most important one according ISO-8601 is even missing. I did not find any [CalendarWeekRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx) property, so it seems to be fixed, but which one?

Comment: I think they just wrap the windows common control, which is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760919(v=vs.85).aspx): "Week 1 is defined as the first week that contains at least four days"

Comment: Apparently not: *The month calendar control displays week numbers (1-52) to the left of each row of days.* This is in contradictory when you go to December 2009 where the last week is 53!

Comment: well, you can choose not to believe me but if you go and look at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/MonthCalendar.cs,703e7d03747f00aa) for the month control, you can see it working with a lot of native code and the `showWeekNumbers` property is used to decide whether to apply a value called `MCS_WEEKNUMBERS` to a style property, which is exactly the documentation I linked to. When using "first week with at least four days", it's actually quite common to end up with a week 53, so it may be wrong documentation

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, yes looks more to be an error in the documentaion.

Comment: btw, "first week with at least four days" is exactly the definition according ISO-8601